# How can I control the search only to certain fields in Lucene

Tags: search, lucene, field

How can I control the search behaviour, for example, all "fields", only in fields of "features, description"? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_4_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Fields